# using variable from file to another file

Tags: python

i have utils file as

```
def load_data(dataset_str):
"""
Loads input data from gcn/data directory

ind.dataset_str.x => the feature vectors of the training instances as scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix object;
ind.dataset_str.tx => the feature vectors of the test instances as scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix object;
ind.dataset_str.allx => the feature vectors of both labeled and unlabeled training instances
    (a superset of ind.dataset_str.x) as scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix object;
ind.dataset_str.y => the one-hot labels of the labeled training instances as numpy.ndarray object;
ind.dataset_str.ty => the one-hot labels of the test instances as numpy.ndarray object;
ind.dataset_str.ally => the labels for instances in ind.dataset_str.allx as numpy.ndarray object;
ind.dataset_str.graph => a dict in the format {index: [index_of_neighbor_nodes]} as collections.defaultdict
    object;
ind.dataset_str.test.index => the indices of test instances in graph, for the inductive setting as list object.

All objects above must be saved using python pickle module.

:param dataset_str: Dataset name
:return: All data input files loaded (as well the training/test data).
"""
names = ['x', 'y', 'tx', 'ty', 'allx', 'ally', 'graph']
objects = []
for i in range(len(names)):
    with open("data/ind.{}.{}".format(dataset_str, names[i]), 'rb') as f:
        if sys.version_info > (3, 0):
            objects.append(pkl.load(f, encoding='latin1'))
        else:
            objects.append(pkl.load(f))
```

and want to use ally variable in this file(train file)

```
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_string('dataset', 'citeseer', 'Dataset string.')  # 'cora', 'citeseer', 'pubmed'
flags.DEFINE_string('model', 'gcn', 'Model string.')  # 'gcn', 'gcn_cheby', 'dense'
flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 'Initial learning rate.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('epochs', 200, 'Number of epochs to train.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('hidden1', 16, 'Number of units in hidden layer 1.')
flags.DEFINE_float('dropout', 0.5, 'Dropout rate (1 - keep probability).')
flags.DEFINE_float('weight_decay', 5e-4, 'Weight for L2 loss on embedding matrix.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('early_stopping', 10, 'Tolerance for early stopping (# of epochs).')
flags.DEFINE_integer('max_degree', 3, 'Maximum Chebyshev polynomial degree.')

# Load data
adj, features, y_train, y_val, y_test, ally, train_mask, val_mask, test_mask = 
load_data(FLAGS.dataset)
```

and i tried to add ally variable in train file specifically in last line as

```
# Load data
adj, features, y_train, y_val, y_test, ally, train_mask, val_mask, test_mask = 
load_data(FLAGS.dataset)
```

but this error appeared
not enough values to unpack (expected 9, got 8)

Comment: Your function returns less values than you have variables to expand the result into. Show us the `return`!